PowerShell Error When Adding Multiple Doc Libraries to SharePoint Online
all.
I am new to PowerShell, but I'm trying to learn it to manage my SharePoint site.
I thought this would be a good opportunity to try something new.
I found a PowerShell script on the SharePoint Diary which adds multiple document libraries to a SharePoint online site, using a .csv template as reference; however, I get the following error message.  Any help would be appreciated.

Error: this is repeated for each library on the .csv file:
Ensuring Document Library 'Team Docs'
        Error: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
New-Object:
Line |
  72 |  … edentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCr …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The 'username' argument cannot be null. (Parameter 'username')"
MethodInvocationException:
Line |
  77 |      $Ctx.executeQuery()
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."


Script: My information removed
>> Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
>> Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
>>
>> #Function to Create a SharePoint Online document library
>> Function CreateSPO-DocumentLibrary()
>> {
>> [cmdletbinding()]
>>     param
>>     (
>>         [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline)] [String] $LibraryName,
>>         [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [String] $Description,
>>         [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [Switch] $ShowOnQuickLaunch
>>     )
>>     Try {
>>             Write-host -f Yellow "`nEnsuring Document Library '$LibraryName'"
>>
>>             #Get All Existing Lists from the web
>>             $Lists = $Web.Lists
>>             $Ctx.Load($Lists)
>>             $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
>>
>>             #Check if Library name doesn't exist already
>>             If(!($Lists.Title -contains $LibraryName))
>>             {
>>                 #Set Quick Launch Option
>>                 If($ShowOnQuickLaunch.IsPresent)
>>                 {
>>                     $QuickLaunchOption = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.QuickLaunchOptions]::On
>>                 }
>>                 Else
>>                 {
>>                     $QuickLaunchOption = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.QuickLaunchOptions]::Off
>>                 }
>>
>>                 #Create Document Library
>>                 $ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
>>                 $ListInfo.Title = $LibraryName
>>                 $ListInfo.Description =  $Description
>>                 $ListInfo.TemplateType =  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary
>>                 $List = $Web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
>>                 $List.OnQuickLaunch = $QuickLaunchOption
>>                 $List.Update()
>>                 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
>>
>>                 write-host  -f Green "`tNew Document Library '$LibraryName' has been created!"
>>             }
>>             Else
>>             {
>>                 Write-Host -f Magenta "`tA Document Library '$LibraryName' Already exists!"
>>             }
>>     }
>>     Catch {
>>         write-host -f Red "`tError:" $_.Exception.Message
>>     }
>> }
>>
>> #Set Parameters
>> $CSVFilePath = "C:\Users\pjones\OneDrive - Advocates for Human Potential\Desktop\CCBHC-E Doc Libraries\DocLibs.csv"
>>
>> #Get Credentials to connect
>> Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenent>-admin.sharepoint.com
>>
>> #Get the CSV file
>> $CSVFile = Import-Csv $CSVFilePath
>>
>> #Read CSV file and create a document library
>> ForEach($Line in $CSVFile)
>> {
>>     #Setup the context
>>     $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Line.SiteURL)
>>     $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
>>
>>     #Get the web from URL
>>     $Web = $Ctx.web
>>     $Ctx.Load($Web)
>>     $Ctx.executeQuery()
>>
>>     #Get the ShowOnQuickLaunch option
>>     $ShowOnQuickLaunch = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($Line.ShowOnQuickLaunch)
>>
>>     #Call the function to create document library
>>     If($ShowOnQuickLaunch -eq $True)
>>     {
>>         CreateSPO-DocumentLibrary -LibraryName $Line.LibraryName -Description $Line.Description -ShowOnQuickLaunch
>>     }
>>     Else
>>     {
>>         CreateSPO-DocumentLibrary -LibraryName $Line.LibraryName -Description $Line.Description
>>     }
>> }


